Llama attention weights shape not looking right
I'm running Llama2 70B from huggingface and I'm using the output_attentions=True argument in Transformers to get the attention weights. It's supposed to output a tuple of (layers, batch size, attention head, input size, input size) but I'm getting a tuple of size (7, 80, 1, 64, input size, input size). What is the extra dimension of 7 supposed to be? Also, I thought causal models were supposed to have lower triangular attention matrices but the output isn't a lower triangle. Why is this?
This is the code that I used
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

model_name = "meta-llama/Llama-2-70b-chat-hf"
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, device_map='auto')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

input_ids = tokenizer([input_prompt], return_tensors="pt")
    outputs= model.generate(
        input_ids['input_ids'],
        do_sample=False,
        temperature=None,
        top_p=None,
        top_k=None,
        max_new_tokens=7,
        sequence_bias=sequence_bias,
        return_dict_in_generate=True,
        output_attentions=True
        )
    attention = outputs.attentions


The tuple outputs.attentions has length 7 because that is the number of new tokens you are generating. The first new token you are generating is based on the last token of the output. The attention weights here will have shape (layers, batch size, attention head, input size, input size). The attention weights for the next token you are generating will have shape (layers, batch size, attention head, 1, input size + 1), since only the attention between the new token and the previous tokens is calculated.
Edit: To ensure that the causal mask is being properly implemented, use attn_implementation="eager" when you do from_pretrained (see https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/30813)

FWIW, if you hackily print out the attention weights from the Llama2 that is on the Meta GitHub page, not hugging face, they are triangular.

Thank you so much! I'll try the weights from the Meta GitHub page
